# Find flipped/mirrored UVs

Tags: uv

I made box mapping to model. 50% of UVs became mirrored. I need to find mirrored parts of UV and scale them to -1. How i can find them?

And second question as part of my problem.
How i can fast show texture grid in viewport. I already have a lot materials with maps. I can't every time switch diffuse map to my custom UV grid texture for checking mapping.